# How to Display Wordpress Custom Fields after 2nd paragraph in a post

Tags: php, wordpress

am using genesis framework. used this code in functions.php file. but displayed data in a table format at the end of post only. But i want to display data after Nth paragraph in a post only.

```
function add_product_spec_to_content($content) {
if(get_field('befestigung') || get_field('gurtsystem') || get_field('gruppe') || get_field('typ') || get_field('amazon') || get_field('bezug') || get_field('gewicht')) { $content = $content . '<table id="product-specification" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><tbody>'; }
if(get_field('befestigung')) { $content = $content . '<tr><td>Befestigung</td><td>' . get_field('befestigung') . '</td></tr>'; }
if(get_field('gurtsystem')) { $content = $content . '<tr><td>Gurtsystem</td><td>' . get_field('gurtsystem') . '</td></tr>'; }
if(get_field('bezug')) { $content = $content . '<tr><td>Bezug</td><td>' . get_field('bezug') . '</td></tr>'; }
if(get_field('gruppe')) { $content = $content . '<tr><td>Gruppe</td><td>' . get_field('gruppe') . '</td></tr>'; }
if(get_field('typ')) { $content = $content . '<tr><td>Typ</td><td>' . get_field('typ') . '</td></tr>'; }
if(get_field('gewicht')) { $content = $content . '<tr><td>Gewicht</td><td>' . get_field('gewicht') . ' kg</td></tr>'; }
if(get_field('amazon')) { $content = $content . '<tr><td>Preis</td><td>' . get_field('amazon') . '</td></tr>'; }
if(get_field('befestigung') || get_field('gurtsystem') || get_field('gruppe') || get_field('typ') || get_field('amazon') || get_field('bezug') || get_field('gewicht')) { $content = $content . '</tbody></table>'; }

return $content; } add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_product_spec_to_content', 1150 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a **shortcode** for this und place it where you want:

```
function sc_my_table( $atts ) {

    $fields = array(
        'befestigung' => 'Befestigung',
        'gurtsystem' => 'Gurtsystem',
        'bezug' => 'Bezug',
        'gruppe' => 'Gruppe',
        'typ' => 'Typ',
        'gewicht' => 'Gewicht',
        'amazon' => 'Preis',        
    );

    $table_open = false;
    $content = '';

    foreach ( $fields as $field => $name ) {

        if ( $value = get_field( $field ) ) {
            if ( ! $table_open ) {
                $content .= '<table id="product-specification" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><tbody>';
                $table_open = true;
            }

            $content .= '<tr><td>'. $name .'</td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
        }
    }

    if ( $table_open ) {
        $content .= '</tbody></table>';     
    }

    return $content;

} 

add_shortcode('my-table', 'sc_my_table');
```

Then use `[my-table]` in text editor at the desired place.

Reference: [add_shortcode()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Comment: You mean my email address? For what?

Comment: am using this code for displaying custom fields in a page

Comment: i have another doubt  http://www.wpbasics.org/2016/03/14/advanced-custom-fields-restaurant-menu/ am using code mentioned in this page to display acf custom fields in page. but it displays value below page content as a separate paragraph. i want include custom fields between page content or just below page content. help me..